# Sharepoint 365 collection administrator has no access to list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have Office 365 SharePoint and am an administrator. I need to gain access to a couple of lists that the people who created them are no longer in the company.

How can I add users as full control to these lists?

Comment: Are you able to open the list and list settings for those lists?

Comment: I think In this case you need to assign yourself site collection admin rights on the sites that host those lists first, there is no transient trust here, as site col admin rights can be separetly audited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have site collection admin permission so that you can access these lists and grant permission to users.

Just go to SharePoint admin center > site collections, select the right site collection and click "Owners" button in the top > click "Manage Administrators" and add yourself into the Site Collection Administrators list. You can refer below article about how to add yourself into site collection admin group(not need to use PowerShell):

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/08/sharepoint-online-add-site-collection-administrator-using-powershell.html

Then you can go to these lists to grant other users full control. You can refer to below article about how to grant full permission to users in list(you need to click "SHOW OPTIONS" to select full permission):

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to add myself to the Site Collections Administrators and now the list has the "Permissions for this list" option.